# htaccess rewrite engine makes trailing hash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason my rewrite engine is adding a random hash to the end of my links such as: #.UHyohWmDRhA

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule   ^about/$   about.php  [NC]
```

So what I expect is localhost/company/about/.  What I get is localhost/company/about/#.UHyohWmDRhA. Anyway to get that to stop?

EDIT------------------------
Well I did not debug this well enough.  My apologies.  All of my links are generating this strange hash.  Will have to investigate further.

EDIT.2------------------------
My mistake.  I have an addthis widget on my headers which is adding the hash.  Will answer in 2 days for whatever it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addthis widget was causing the hash.

Edit-------------
The site I'm working on has an addthis.com plugin to share the site.  There was an option in this plugin which tracks when someone copies and pastes the link somewhere.  The hash is what is used to track this copy/paste action.  You can remove the line in the plugin to remove this option (or keep it).

TL;DR: Check your script plugins if your url is being modified.

Comment: In case anybody else has a similar problem.. perhaps you could fill this out a bit more and explain how it was causing your problem and why the solution worked for you. Don't forget: other people might google when they have a similar problem and find your question and want to solve it using your answer.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$  $1/  [L]
```

Comment: Hash still comes up.  I wonder if it is a setting in my apache?

Comment: Out of curiosity are you using .htaccess or placing the mod_rewrite statements in the host directive on apache?